# How to get a django field value throw a custom models.Field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-custom-field

I have a custom field:

```
class MyCustomTextField(models.Field):
(...)
```

and use that on my model:

```
class MyModel():
  encrypted_password = MyCustomTextField(null=True)
  password_seed = models.TextField(null=True)
```

I need when I use MyModel to grab  `encrypted_password`, I need to grab first `password_seed` and return a new value using the `password_seed` value.

How can I do that, since custom model is instantiate before the data comes to the model?

Comment: You can override save method and add the logic you need.

Comment: @ariaman5  I'm looking for something more "wide", into the custom field class, so I can use it for all models, overriding the save method, I need to do it for each model I use

Comment: Does other models have encrypted_password and password_seed too? I think it has nothing to do with the custom field. Maybe you can use inheritance for the models.

Comment: Yeah, all inherited  models have those fields. But I think I need something "general" not one by one (models)

Answer (score 0):

read this article [from Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-model-fields/). you should override the method

> def deconstruct(self): ...

of MyCustomTextField